Access /sys/bus/w1/ from kernel module
I am new to kernel device driver development(or Linux development). I currently have a 1-wire memory device that shows up in /sys/bus/w1/devices/w1_bus_master1/. There I can read the eeprom and other features. But now I would like to create a module that could be accessed from userspace that decodes the contents from that memory.
So basically my goal is:
W1 Device driver <--> DS24xxx <--> My module > User space application.
I tried already with filp_open() but I am not able to read. I am using a kernel v6.1. Is this the right way to do what I want to achieve or is there a better approach? I read that is not recommended to perform file IO operations in kernel. Would appreciate any guidance.

The w1 eeprom drivers do not seem to expose anything to other kernel drivers, so you are stuck with using filp_open etc. Have you tried to use the kernel_read function?

@IanAbbott, one may always modify the kernel to provide necessary APIs. I believe that memory should be exposed via nvmem framework (IIRC).

@0andriy That would be ideal, but the only w1 eeprom driver that registers with the nvmem framework is w1_ds250x.

Sorry for the late reply. Yes with kernel read it works now.
